# Polymer 1.0 Neon Animation for DOM attributes

Tags: javascript, animation, polymer, polymer-1.0

I've been trying to animate some DOM attributes with Polymer but had no luck. The thing is that i'm trying to animate inline attributes of some custom elements, SVGs or text values. Also trying to use animation runtime to run some custom JS functions.

I've noticed that 'requesAnimationFrame' (or 'acync' in Polymer's case) doesn't work properly for smooth animations.

Also tried to find somethings inside Neon Animations to deal with elements inline attributes but found nothing. Everything i've seen in Neon Animations is related to CSS styling.

Does anyone knows a good way to do so in Polymer.

thanks in advance.

Comment: what kinds of attribs are you wanting to "animate", how how do the attribs  visually manifest themselves?

Comment: In this case i'm trying to animate the "d" parameter of a SVGs path, it is a long string and i have a JS function to generate it. I'm also trying to animate a number string... like a number that goes form "0" to "100", but should fallow the timing of the SVG's "d" parameter easing...

Comment: D3 has a lot of tools for animating SVG and even more stuff for scaling ranges of values, which is the hard path about computing animation callbacks... You don't have to go "all in" to D3, just use its util functions.

Comment: I undestan, but i'm looking for a more integrated solution for Polymer. In many cases (also in this project) i'm trying to animate a attribute of a custom element, created with Polymer. D3 wouldn't help .

Comment: i don't see why D3 wouldn't help with that. its got a lot of attrib-moding tools, many of them trying in nicely to thier scales, which makes slowly changing an attrib over time between a range of values trivial... It works on SVG, html, custom elements, anything with a DOM. if you don't want to bite off the whole thing, look at how they code their utils for inspiration.

Comment: You say i could use D3's built in tween system to change any non SVG element's attributes?

Comment: absolutely; i use the number-crunching helpers/scalers in several projects that don't even have charts or SVG. i know it's not obvious or advertised, but aside from the charting, there's a lot of good static utilities in there that are great for sliding/scaling/animating values. think of D3 as a more holistic jQuery. to be fair, you could hand-tween and increment each of your transitions by hand, but even doing that, D3 can cut the hand-written code down from 10-20 lines to 3-4 lines per routine...

Comment: @dandavis I've tried exacly this approach using GreenSock Tweeners... thing is: As those plugins rely in "requestAnimationFrame" to work the integration with Polymer is shown to be very difficult. Polymer (don't know if is a bug) runs many more than 60 fps in 'requestAnimationFrame' and the results looks strange. Also Buggy. I'm trying to find a more integrates solution, maybe Neon Animations, which are build for Polymer's runtime. Do you know anything about it? thanks'

Comment: hmmm. i don't see the connection from rAF() to polymer, looking through the source. my guess is that polymer/your data is simply too slow to handle 60FPS. this could be verified by using a short hand-written animation routine that simply alters the attribs; if it's still "choppy", then no tool will help.